# A system of linear equations with 3 variables such that its solution set is: $\{(a,b,c)|a^2=b \}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

> Is there a system of linear equations with 3 variables such that its solution set is: $\{(a,b,c)|a^2=b  \}$?

It's enough to show that for one equation: $Ax+By+Cz=D$ the solution set doesn't work.

Take $(0,0,c)$ for all $c$ we have $Cc=D$ which can hold only if $C=D=0$.

So we have a homogeneous equation: $Ax+By=0$ and from placing the solutions $(1,1,0),(-1,1,0)$ we get that $A=B=0$.

Now I'm not sure how this contradicts the solution set.

Comment: Note that any solution set of a homogeneous system of linear equations has to be a vector space.

Comment: @sranthrop isn't the trivial solution also considered a space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution set of such a system has to be a plane in 3 dimensions. So you cannot have a solution set such as you describe.

Comment: Why doesn't the "space" $0x+0y+0z=0$ work? why is it different from say $1x+0y+0z=0$?

Comment: I'm sorry O did oversimplify a bit. If the system is homogeneous and nonsingular, then ${(0,0,0)}$ a solution set.

Comment: Here we have a homogeneous and non singular system and $(0,0,0)$ is one of the solutions. I still don't understand...

Comment: I got what you meant but it's supposed to be solved without relying on spanning vector space (which hasn't been covered yet). 
$$ $$
In my solution I get: $0x+0y+0z=0$ but any solution from the given solution set would solve this. Is this even close to a contradiction?